# Why is the public key extracted from the CSR different than the one extracted from the associated certificate?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, python

I am playing around with pyopenssl. I am trying to extract the public key from a CSR and to check if it is the same than the one I find in the associated certificate.

There is a small difference between the two than I can't explain.

From the <s>certificate</s> CSR:

```
30 61 02 01 00 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 04 4D 30 4B 02 01 00 02 41 00 A4 BF 6C 40 D5 46 98 AA B8 E5 6B 9C 65 05 7A D5 C7 80 D0 47 83 06 C7 7A 64 89 D5 AA 68 84 2C 8E E4 2D C2 4E 98 61 FC 29 57 3D D9 E9 BC 7E 14 28 2C 49 A7 BF CE C3 6C D2 75 63 89 40 58 06 CC C3 02 03 01 00 01
```

From the <s>CSR</s> certificate:

```
30 48 02 41 00 A4 BF 6C 40 D5 46 98 AA B8 E5 6B 9C 65 05 7A D5 C7 80 D0 47 83 06 C7 7A 64 89 D5 AA 68 84 2C 8E E4 2D C2 4E 98 61 FC 29 57 3D D9 E9 BC 7E 14 28 2C 49 A7 BF CE C3 6C D2 75 63 89 40 58 06 CC C3 02 03 01 00 01
```

You can see that the beginning is different:

```
30 61 02 01 00 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 04 4D 30 4B 02 01 00

30 48
```

Could you help me out?

Also, I use the method crypto.dump_privatekey(), but I think that it gives back the public key if applied to the CSR.
Is it correct? 
And is there a way to extract the public key from the certificate directly?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
PEM = SSL.FILETYPE_PEM

# Create a key set and a CSR:

pkey = crypto.PKey()
pkey.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 512)

csr = crypto.X509Req()
csr.get_subject().CN = 'Test'
csr.set_pubkey(pkey)
csr.sign(pkey, "sha256")

# Extract the public key from the CSR:
pkey = csr.get_pubkey()
pkey_str_pub = crypto.dump_privatekey(PEM, pkey)

# Remove the first and last line of the PEM
pkey_list_pub = pkey_str_pub.splitlines(True)[1:-1]
pkey_str_pub = ''.join(pkey_list_pub)

# Convert to hex
pkey_bin_pub = binascii.a2b_base64(pkey_str_pub)
pkey_hex_pub = binascii.b2a_hex(pkey_bin_pub)

# Uppercase and blocks of 2 char
pkey_nice_pub = ' '.join(pkey_hex_pub[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0,len(pkey_hex_pub),2)).upper()

print pkey_nice_pub # Gives the second line


# For the associated certificate now

cert = crypto.X509()

cert.set_serial_number(serial)
cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(notBefore)
cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(notAfter)

cert.set_subject(csr.get_subject())
cert.set_pubkey(csr.get_pubkey())

cert.set_issuer(ca_cert.get_subject())
cert.sign(ca_pkey, "sha256")

cert_pem = crypto.dump_certificate(PEM, cert) # Gives the cert with the first line
```

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know the python, but your values appear to be looking at two different levels, and one is wrong. Both an X.509 cert and a PKCS#10 CSR contain a "subjectPublicKeyInfo" field which is a SEQUENCE of **two** things. The first is an AlgorithmIdentifier which is a SEQUENCE of (always) the OID for the algorithm and (sometimes) parameters whose presence and type vary depending on the algorithm. The second is a BITSTRING containing the actual key in an algorithm-dependent encoding, which for RSA is a SEQUENCE of two INTEGERs, n the modulus and e the public exponent. ...

Comment: ... Your "CSR" value is `30 48` SEQUENCE of `02 41 00 A4 ... C3 02 03 01 00 01` 2 INTEGERs n and e which is correct for the alg-specific part, but missing the rest.
Your "cert" value is `30 61` SEQUENCE of `02 01 00` INTEGER 0 **wrong** `30 0D ... 05 00` the right AlgId for RSA (with params NULL) `04 4D 30 4B 02 01 00 02 41 00 A4 ... C3 02 03 01 00 01` OCTETSTRING **wrong** containing SEQUENCE of three INTEGERs (0,n,e) **wrong**. I don't know whether your cert is actually wrong or only your display of it, but hope this helps some.

Comment: It occurred to me that your "cert" value is actually closer to the PKCS#8 format for a **private** key; that does use INTEGERs for version, and OCTETSTRING. But it isn't used for a public key and is not legal in a cert. Also, I assume you do realize that RSA 512-bits is **way** too small to be secure.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.

After reading what you wrote, I looked more into the details and I realized that I inverted the CSR and cert sequences in my question…

To read the certificate I use gcr-viewer which is the default GUI for that purpose in Ubuntu. This tool has a Public Key Info section which contains different subsections: Key Algorithm (RSA), Key Parameters (05 00), Key Size (512), Key SHA1 Fingerprint and Public Key. The string I pasted for the cert is supposed to be the Public Key only.

Comment: So what you say makes sense and we have for the cert:
Start (30 48) + Exponent (02 … BF) + Modulus (6C … C3) + End (02 … 01). And for the CSR: Start (30 61) + Param (02 … 00 ) + Exponent (02 … BF) + Modulus (6C … C3) + End (02 … 01). I Noticed that the Start, the End and the Parameters are the same for all the cert and CSR that I create.

The 512b key was just used for the question because it is easier to read :)

I think I have my answer then. Thank you!

Comment: Not quite. The now-labelled-cert is indeed only the actual key part and is broken up as `30 48` SEQUENCE `02 41 00 A4 BF ... CC C3` INTEGER modulus (always large) `02 03 01 00 01` INTEGER public exponent (usually small and very often this exact value hex 10001 = dec 65537, which your viewer may display). now-CSR is `30 61` SEQUENCE (header) `02 01 00` INTEGER (version?) '30 0D ...` AlgId including OID *and* params (which are indeed `05 00` NULL for RSA) `04 4D 30 4B` *OCTETSTRING containing SEQUENCE* `02 01 00` INTEGER (version?) then the modulus and pub-expt same as above.

Comment: Okay size 512 was just a test. Be aware for sizes over about 1000 bits (including all adequately secure sizes) most of the ASN.1 elements will use a 2-byte or 3-byte length, and thus a 3 or 4 byte prefix instead of 2, so this will change the layout slightly from the one here.